# Anvil on node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I'm trying to use Anvil (tool for pdf-filling). I try to use their node-anvil solution (https://github.com/anvilco/node-anvil). The instruction there says that I should use the following code to fill and download generated PDF:

```
const Anvil = require('@anvilco/anvil');
const fs = require('fs');

// PDF template you uploaded to Anvil
const pdfTemplateID = 'TEMPLATEID'

// Your API key from your Anvil organization settings
const apiKey = 'MYAPIKEY'

// JSON data to fill the PDF
const payload = {
  "title": "My PDF Title",
  "fontSize": 10,
  "textColor": "#CC0000",
  "data": {
    "Name": "Sample name"
  }
}
// The 'options' parameter is optional
const options = {
  "dataType": "buffer"
}
const anvilClient = new Anvil({ apiKey })

const { statusCode, data } = await anvilClient.fillPDF(pdfTemplateID, payload, options)

console.log(statusCode);



// Be sure to write the file as raw bytes
fs.writeFileSync('filled.pdf', data, { encoding: null })
```

Problem is that node gives me the SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function. I lack the knowledge of how to rewrite it to make it work. Can you advise me please?

Answer (score 0):

Their sample code is badly written. Made it work with:

```
    async function getData() {
            const { statusCode, data } = await anvilClient.fillPDF(pdfTemplateID, payload, options);
            console.log(statusCode);
            fs.writeFileSync('filled.pdf', data, { encoding: null })
        }
        
   getData();
```